# swift google maps open modal on marker tap

Tags: ios, swift

Within my swift app I used to open up a infowindow when a map marker was tapped. I am in the process of changing this instead to open up a viewcontroller as a modal and present the information in it instead. The problem I'm encountering is that the modal doesn't present from when a map marker is tapped. The map marker gets called, the data I need is passed to the controller but the controller itself won't appear. It looks to exist as when I tap the marker a second time, it'll error out about the activity already presenting.

Here is the code on tapping the marker

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    mapView.animate(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude))
    detailsViewController.marker = marker
    present(detailsViewController, animated: true)
    return true
}
```

The viewcontroller does present correctly if not done with a map marker. If I tap a button and call the present, it show as it should.

Anyone do something like this, have an idea of what needs to be changed, or have some code they can share?

---

Update: it mysteriously started working so the code is correct. No change. Just rebuilt a few times. Even clean didn't resolve it but building it numerous times did.